# onBeforeUpdate and onUpdate not triggering on Quasar Vue project

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, quasar-framework

I have a simple app with three things:

- counter
- button that increases counter
- onBeforeUpdate and onUpdate hooks

**VERY IMPORTANT**: I tried to replicate this on a pure Vue Vite project and I had NO problem there. The onBeforeUpdate and onUpdate hooks did trigger, so I must be Quasar specific or I must be missing something.

Project:
[image]
When I press the increase button the onBeforeUpdate and onUpdate hooks DON'T trigger (they should just do some console.log)

**Reproduction URL**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/quasarframework-aj9suk?file=src/pages/IndexPage.vue

**How to reproduce?**

1. Go to link and wait until the project loads (you see text and btn)
2. Open console (F12 or Right click and Inspect)
3. Click the button, counter should increase, but the methods won't trigger

**Relevant packages:**

- NodeJs - 16.15.0
- NPM - 8.19.2
- quasar - 2.8.3
- @quasar/app-vite - 1.1.1
- vue - 3.2.39
- vue-router - 4.1.5

**Code:**

```js
<template>
  <q-page class="flex flex-center">
    <div class="q-pa-lg">
      Open console, you will see that onBeforeUpdate and onUpdated are not being
      triggered when counter is being changed
    </div>
    <div>{{ counter }}</div>
    <button @click="counter++">Increase</button>
  </q-page>
</template>

<script>
import {
  ref,
  onUpdated,
  onBeforeUpdate,
} from 'vue';
export default {
  setup() {
    const increaseCounter = () => {
      counter.value++;
    };
    let counter = ref(1);

    onBeforeUpdate(() => {
      debugger;
      console.log('onBeforeUpdate');
    });
    onUpdated(() => {
      debugger;
      console.log('onBeforeUpdate');
    });
    console.log('setup');

    return {
      increaseCounter,
      counter
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are rendering your variable inside the `q-page` component so the hook of the parent component will not be triggered.
Let's consider [this example](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

```html
<!-- App.vue -->
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
import { onUpdated } from 'vue'
import Test from './Test.vue'

const counter1 = ref(1)
const counter2 = ref(2)
onUpdated(() => {
  console.log('on updated')
})
</script>

<template>
  <Test>
    Counter 1: {{ counter1 }} <br />
    Counter 2: {{ counter2 }} <br />
  </Test>
  <br />
  Counter 1: {{ counter1 }} <br />
  <button @click="counter1++">Increase counter 1</button>
  <button @click="counter2++">Increase counter 2</button>
</template>
```

```html
<!-- Test.vue -->
<template>
  <div class="test">
    <h1>Test component</h1>
    <slot></slot>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { onUpdated } from 'vue'
onUpdated(() => {
  console.log('on updated inside test component')
})
</script>
```

When you click on the `Increase counter 1` button the hook `onUpdated` will be triggered in both `App.vue` and `Test.vue`.

But when you click on the `Increase counter 2` button, the hook `onUpdated` will be triggered in only the `Test.vue` component. Because the `counter1` variable is rendered inside both `App.vue` and `Test.vue` components. And the `counter2` variable is rendered only inside the `Test.vue` components